# Using Angular value service in directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I have a directive that needs to display data stored in a value service. It looks something like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.value('user', {})
.run(['user', function (user) {
    // "user" value is set by result of $http.get(),
    // but hard-coding value for example purposes
    user = {
        name: 'Foo'
    };
}])
.directive('userProfile', ['user', function (user) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.user = user;
        },
        template: '<span>User name: {{ user.name }}</span>'
    };
}]);
```

When the directive's controller gets the injected `user` object, however, it's `undefined`. Am I missing something?

Here's the live code to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/8433/

Answer (score 0):

[working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/csrow/HB7LU/8434/)

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.value('user', {})
.run(['user', function (user) {
    // "user" value is set by result of $http.get(),
    // but hard-coding value for example purposes
    user.hardCoded = {
        name: 'Foo'
    };
}])
.directive('userProfile', ['user', function (user) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.user = user.hardCoded;
        },
        template: '<span>User name: {{ user.name }}</span>'
    };
}]);
```

Since a directive creates its own scope, you can go up one level by using prototype chaining.

Instead of using just 'user' object, add a dot.

Answer (score 0):

here is working example

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/8460/

try below code

```
     angular.module('myApp', [])
    .value('user', {name:'foo'})

   .directive('userProfile', ['user', function (user) {
    return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.user = user;
    },
    template: '<span>User name: {{ user.name }}</span>'
};
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your run function deferences the user variable

Consider the following portion of your code:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.run(['user', function (user) {
    // "user" value is set by result of $http.get(),
    // but hard-coding value for example purposes
    user = {
        name: 'Foo'
    };
}]);
```

Instead of setting the properties of the `angular.value("user")`, you are re-referencing the user parameter to point to somthing else.
You should do this instead:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.run(['user', function (user) {
    // "user" value is set by result of $http.get(),
    // but hard-coding value for example purposes
    user.name = "Foo";
    // you are setting the properties of user
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `angular.extend()` in this instance, wherein you modify or add properties from an existing object from another object. The advantage of this approach is you don't have to manually assign each property to the user object.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/h9bhr5Kg0wJdyQfqe5ip?p=preview)**

**Javascript**

```
angular.module('app', [])

  .value('user', {})

  .run(function($http, user) {
    $http.get('user.json').success(function(data) {
      angular.extend(user, data);
    });
  })

  .directive('userProfile', ['user', function (user) {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          controller: function ($scope) {
              $scope.user = user;
          },
          template: '<span>User name: {{ user.name }}</span>'
      };
  }]);
```